# How can I take a capture of google map when I was clicking one button?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Here I got stucked with one functionality in my demo page. Here I want to take a snapshot of what i can see (google map) which is adjustable by user.

Now I want when I was click one button i take the screenshot which I saw on the screen and open this screen shot in that window below the map and also i want to download that screenshot.

Here I can put my demo code here. In this code where I can insert that code and which code is usuful for it.

Hope for getting very fast reply with positive answer.

Thank You in Advance...

My Code IS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

`<head><title></title>
</head><body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">`

```
var markers = [
        {
            "title": 'Abingdon',
            "lat": '40.803572',
            "lng": '-90.400770',
            "description": 'Abingdon is a city in Knox County, Illinois, 50 miles (80 km) west of Peoria. It is part of the Galesburg Micropolitan Statistical Area. The city was first settled in 1828 and was incorporated in 1857. In 1894, the patent for the common spring-loaded mousetrap was awarded to William Hooker of Abingdon. In 1890, 1,321 people lived here; in 1900, 2,022; and in 1910, 2,464. The population was 3,612 at the 2000 census.'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Cedar Rapids',
            "lat": '41.9831',
            "lng": '-91.6686',
            "description": 'A flourishing center for arts and culture in Eastern Iowa, the city is home to the Cedar Rapids Museum of Art, the National Czech & Slovak Museum & Library, the Paramount Theatre, Theatre Cedar Rapids, the African-American Historical Museum and Cultural Center of Iowa, and the Iowa Cultural Corridor Alliance. Cedar Rapids is an economic hub of the state, located in the core of the Interstate 380.'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Chicago',
            "lat": '41.8369',
            "lng": '-87.6847',
            "description": 'Chicago was incorporated as a city in 1837, near a portage between the Great Lakes and the Mississippi River watershed, and grew rapidly in the mid-nineteenth century.[7] The city is an international hub for finance, commerce, industry, technology, telecommunications, and transportation: OHare International Airport is the busiest airport in the world when measured by aircraft traffic; it also has the largest number of U.S. highways and rail road freight.'
        }
    ,
        {
            "title": 'Orland Park',
            "lat": '41.6073508',
            "lng": '-87.8616741',
            "description": 'Orland Park is a village in Cook County, Illinois, United States, and a middle-class suburb of Chicago which in 2010 had a population of 56,767.'
        }
    ];
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });
            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Intialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Intialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#252365' });

        //Loop and Draw Path Route between the Points on MAP
        for (var i = 0; i < lat_lng.length; i++) {
            if ((i + 1) < lat_lng.length) {
                var src = lat_lng[i];
                var des = lat_lng[i + 1];
                path.push(src);
                poly.setPath(path);
                service.route({
                    origin: src,
                    destination: des,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
                }, function (result, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                            path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 700px; height: 500px">
</div>
```